# What will be the Indirect form of the sentence - Ron said, "Jean will look after the dogs while we are away." -

Tags: reported-speech

The answer given in textbook is  - Ron said that Jean would look after the dogs while they were away.

But this doesnt seems right. "were" sounds wrong

Comment: Hi , Welcome to ELL! This is not the right place to get your homework done, so please edit your question by adding some information/what made you write this question.

Comment: That is not a transformation to passive, but a transformation from direct speech to indirect speech.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the textbook answer, if it is meant to be indirect speech. However, if the person reporting the speech is speaking before the dog-owners go away, "Ron said that Jean will look after the dogs while they are away" would also be correct.